# PHP error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->'

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am new to PHP. I am trying to create a textbox in html, and take the input via php and store it in my Mysql database.

I can't get past this error.

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)**

I understand the `->` is wrong. But I don't know how to fix it.

Also is there any other errors that you guys see in this code? I appreciate your help.

```php
    <form action="user-post.php" method="get">
    <input type="post-box" name="postbox" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php 

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['message'] = '';

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost:3306', 'root', '1234', 'status-box');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    $postbox = mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['postbox']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO post (postbox)"
           . "VALUES ('$postbox')";

    if ($mysqli->query($sql) === true) {
        header("location: index.html");
    } else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Post could NOT be added to the database!";
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: `mysqli` should be `$mysqli` on the real_escape line

Comment: escaping your input is not a secure way to prevent SQL injection. use parameterised statements instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*you have forgotten the dollars*/
mysqli should become
$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['postbox']);
```

Comment: When the answer is "you forgot the dollar sign", there is no need to answer. Just leave a comment under the question and flag/vote to close as Off-topic: Typo. This page will be quickly scrubbed from the site (as will any upvote points you receive) because this page is completely useless to researchers. See: [Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232).

Answer (score 0):

Just Copy and Paste this, You may be a mistake in

> mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['postbox']);

just change it to

> $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['postbox']);

real_escape_string($_GET['postbox']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO post (postbox)"
           . "VALUES ('$postbox')";

    if ($mysqli->query($sql) === true) {
        header("location: index.html");
    } else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Post could NOT be added to the database!";
    }

}

?>

Comment: When the answer is "you forgot the dollar sign", there is no need to answer. Just leave a comment under the question and flag/vote to close as Off-topic: Typo. This page will be quickly scrubbed from the site (as will any upvote points you receive) because this page is completely useless to researchers. See: [Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232).